# How can I use axios to handle expired token when the main api fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using axios to call an API, How can I handle expired token call when the main API fails with the same reason, I have implemented a generateToken call to get the updated token and subsequently making a request to the same API with the updated token in case the token expired?

This is the code I have written which is not perfect and it is going in infinite loop with the same response

```
export const getAllStates = async (payload) => {
    headers = { ...headers, 'Authorization': getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage() };
 
    try {
        let response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/geo/states`, { headers: headers, data: {}});
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in response ', error.message);

        let response;
        if (error.response?.data?.status === 'FAILURE' && error.response?.data?.message === 'ACCESS_DENIED') {
            await getToken();     // making a call to get a new token
            response = await getAllStates(payload);   // calling that api again
            return response;
        }
        return error?.response;
    }
}
```

```
export const getToken = async () => {
    const resposne = await generateToken();

    if (resposne.status === 'SUCCESS' && resposne.message === 'SUCCESS') {
      saveAccessTokenInLocalStorage(resposne.data.token);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to handle expired token calls and generating a new token then making the request?